# How to calculate cosine similarity on a list of embeddings

Tags: cosine-similarity, python-embedding

I'm doing a project for a university exam on Python. I'm analyzing the scripts of the dialogues of a sample of Doctor Who'episodes. They have already been tokenized for sentence with spacy and put in a file txt.
My tokenized text is way way longer than 512 (several thousands), which is the limit for the token elaboration for the transformers. For this reason i created a for cycle to iterate on every tokenized sentence creating an embedding. The embeddings of all the sentences are then put in a list. My goal is to obtain the value of the cosine similarity between all the embeddings' values. My final goal is to compare the value of the cosine similarity between several other texts of episodes obtaining the mean value.
In the following script, as a first step, i was trying to obtain che cosine similarity.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

with open("/content/drive/MyDrive/tokenized_episode.txt", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()

def compute_cosine_similarity(text):
  embedding_text = []
  model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')  
  for phrase in text:
    embedding = model.encode([phrase])
    embedding_text.append(embedding)
    similarity = cosine_similarity(embedding_text)
    print(similarity)

compute_cosine_similarity(text)
```

Why does it give me this error ? "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1"